# Memory usage constraints on thread count using PLINQ

Tags: c#, .net, plinq

I'm using PLINQ to data-parallelize an operation. Each thread consumes a very large amount of memory which is variable based on algorithm settings, there's no easy way to pre-calculate how much memory will be required based on the algorithm options. When memory requirements are low, the optimal # of threads is 7 out of system total of 8; when memory requirements are high, 2 threads is a significant improvement over 1, but once 3 threads are used the system starts hitting the paging file and CPU utilization drops down to 0 and performance becomes hundreds of times worse.

What I'd like to be able to do is have PLINQ increase the # of threads incrementally, while monitoring the memory load, and once the system exhausts available physical memory, set the cancellation token on the last thread so it can rollback its memory, allowing the other threads to execute optimally.

Any ideas on how to get this behavior out of PLINQ or do I have to roll-my-own entirely?

Comment: As far as I know, PLINQ decides the number of threads up front and it remains constant for the execution of the question. You can't do anything about that (except changing that constant by calling `WithDegreeOfParallelism()`). If you were using `Parallel.ForEach()` instead, you might have a better chance: using a custom `TaskScheduler`.

Answer (score 1):

PLINQ uses `TreadPool` Threads (with default `TaskScheduler` and `TaskFactory`) so you may use `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(#N, #Q)` to control number of threads based on current memory consumption of your app.

But it seems to me, memory consumption of that magnitude is an app, maybe should be redesigned and pushed to another module (like a database - a lite RDBMS or NoSQL one - or a caching system) - just a suggestion.